# Is there a specific procedure to deploy a smart contract/dapp to the public network (Mainnet)?

Tags: contract-design, contract-deployment, dapp-development

I would like to know if there are any rules (coding rules and verification steps to be taken) that should be taken care of and controlled by someone who is maintaining the Mainnet such as the Ethereum Consortium etc. while deploying a smart contract / dapp to the Ethereum public network (Mainnet)?

And is it obligatory to provide the source of the smart contract/dapp in a git repository or not?

Or can anyone without being controlled by someone else deploy his/her app to Mainnet as he/she wants?

I have found these related questions but they do not answer to my question.

- [how to deploy smart contract in ethereum network using ropsten network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19415/how-to-deploy-smart-contract-in-ethereum-network-using-ropsten-network)
- [What are explicit steps to deploy dapp to mainnet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24807/what-are-explicit-steps-to-deploy-dapp-to-mainnet)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no control done by anyone. You are free to deploy whatever you want and it is not mandatory to publish the source code.

Now, given the current state of the ecosystem. Probably very few prople will use your contract without having access to reading the code, specially if it involves sending ether.